# IntelliJ idea hidden Run Configurations

Tags: intellij-idea

I encountered strange problem. After fresh install of IntelliJ Idea 2016.1 and configuring two *Run Configurations*, I noticed, that one is missing from *Run* menu. So I opened *Edit Configurations...* and there were both of them. Then by accident, I left the other configuration selected when closing *Edit Configurations...* dialog. And bam, first Run Configuration dissapeared and second (one highlighted when leaving *Edit Configurations...*) appeared in *Run* menu. Can somebody tell me, how to display both? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. 'Run' menu item now takes 'Run Configuration' selected in this panel on the right side [position of Run panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSqow.png). Hope this helps some other folks.

Answer (score 0):

I can verify this behaviour. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1 too.

I think that is no bug, because you can find all your run configurations when you click on `Select Rub/Debug Configuration` in the toolbar.

The purpose of the menu `Run` isn't to offer all the configurations. There can be dozens.
[image: Button for selecting run configurations]